# How loop the data and set it as it goes on

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have tried and set the script as my api returns me set of 2500 value only so I have looped the data by pages. And I do not know how to set the data after the first 2500 value.

Someone please help me..

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  pullJSON(i);
}
function pullJSON(i) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();



    var url = "http://myapi&_page="+i; // Paste your JSON URL here
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "API Key"
    };
    var options = {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": headers
    };


    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options); // get feed
    var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
    var dataSet = dataAll;
    Logger.log(dataAll.length);



    var rows = [],
        data;

    for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {


        data = dataSet[i];
        var utcSeconds = data.createDate;
        var d = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
        d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
        rows.push([data.id, data.c_customer_id, data.firstName, data.email, d]); //your JSON entities here
    }

    dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, rows.length, 5); // 3 Denotes total number of entites
    dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are always overwriting the old data starting in row two.
You may want to overwrite the data overall but not by iteration.

You can append the new data after the old data by setting the range like this:

```
dataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 2, rows.length, 5);
```

And if you want to overwrite the old data with the pull itself without leaving any old data left over in case you ever end up with fewer rows you can put

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(2 , 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 5).clear();
```

At the beginning before running the loop with the `pullJSON` call

Comment: Thanks Robin. Its working now. But I am getting a problem with the for loop. Its looping the same value again and again if the condition more.. How to loop the data set only once.

Comment: you are using `i` as the iterator in both the loop running `pullJSON` and inside the function to extract the results, the `i` inside the function does not have the `var` keyword and is thus global. Try using a different name for one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to respond to me.

Tried using a different name its still looping twice. 
for(var i=0;i< 5;i++){
  pullJSON(i);
}

function pullJSON(k)

Have changed the iterator as k instead of (i)  in all places. But I have not defined k. Is that still okay? if no may I know what should I define it as.

Comment: Did you also rename the iterator in the loop in the function? It's hard to debug from here without access to the api

Comment: Yes, and I added the for iterator logger.log (k) file as well. This was the result. Does while looping work in this cases?.

([16-09-30 20:43:10:162 IST] 2500.0
[16-09-30 20:43:10:162 IST] 0.0
[16-09-30 20:43:18:876 IST] 2500.0
[16-09-30 20:43:18:877 IST] 1.0
[16-09-30 20:43:28:342 IST] 2500.0
[16-09-30 20:43:28:342 IST] 2.0
[16-09-30 20:43:35:710 IST] 1648.0
[16-09-30 20:43:35:711 IST] 3.0
[16-09-30 20:43:50:034 IST] 1648.0
[16-09-30 20:43:50:034 IST] 4.0
[16-09-30 20:43:59:062 IST] 2500.0
[16-09-30 20:43:59:063 IST] undefined)